# Tailwind CSS horizontal scrolling when content overflows

Tags: tailwind-css

Using Tailwind CSS, I want to apply the scrolling effect when the content is too large to fit the screen width. I have a div container that holds the child elements, which I want to scroll. When I use a section to hold the image and the username (shown below), they all shrink to fit the screen size. This is not what I want. I want only a few sections to appear and the rest when I scroll. What am I missing?

Not working

```
<div class="flex overflow-x-auto space-x-8">
<section class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
  <span><img src="download.jfif" class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""></span>
   <span>John</span>
</section>
<section class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
  <span><img src="download.jfif" class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""></span>
   <span>John</span>
</section>
<section class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
  <span><img src="download.jfif" class="h-13 w-13 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""></span>
   <span>John</span>
</section> 
</div>
```

If I put it like below, it's working, but I do not want it this way.

```
<div class="flex overflow-x-auto space-x-5"> 
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">    
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">    
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">    
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">    
      <img src="download.jfif" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" alt="Bhutan">    
</div>
```

Comment: `its working but it's not want it this way` Why? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 26):

First, 13 is not a valid value for height/width. (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) That likely causes some of your issues.

You can put `flex-shrink-0` on all the `section` elements to prevent the images from shrinking instead of scrolling.

But as you've defined the fixed width of the `section` to be the same as the image, you will also get vertical scrolling.

Check out the following example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex overflow-x-auto space-x-8 w-1/2 bg-red-200">
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
  <section class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300">
    <span><img src="download.jfif" class="bg-purple-200 h-14 w-14 rounded-full border-2 border-purple-300" alt=""
    /></span>
    <span>John</span>
  </section>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/4B5d6ne1s5